# Migrating "File History" from Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 10

Tags: windows-8.1, backup, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

Currently I am using `File History` on my Windows 8.1 Pro machine to backup all my data to an additional disk drive. Now I would like to migrate to Windows 10 Pro by reinstalling the whole system (no in-place upgrade).

Will my backup still be readable after a fresh Windows 10 installation? Is there some form of migration task I need to perform on the data beforehand?

Comment: To add some information to my own question: After doing an in-place upgrade I was still able to access my `File History`. Next step will be a clean installation and see if Windows can still access the backup... I will report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes, after a clean Windows 10 installation `File History` is still able to read the old backups which reside on a seperate disk.